# Python 3: How do I assert that the value of a gobject.GParamSpec is of a particular type?

Tags: python, gnome, gimp, pygobject, gobject

I'm writing GIMP 2.99 python plugins. All of the arguments in a Gimp `Procedure` are held as an array of `GParamSpec` instances. I want to assert that each argument value is the type I expect. My problem is that everything is either wrapped, and/or mapped, and sparsely documented for Python. (In this case, as a GType). So simple uses of python 3.0's `instanceOf()` and "`is`" operator can't do what I want.
For example, I want to know that arg[0] is a "`Gimp.RunMode`"

```
def assert_layers_procedure(procedure):
    #  An array of GParamSpec
    procedure_args_raw = procedure.get_arguments()
    # The first GParamSpec
    arg_zero_raw = procedure_args_raw[0]
    arg_zero_type = arg_zero_raw.value_type
    # Apparently, arg_zero_type is a "GType GimpRunMode (4194814752)"
    if arg_zero_type is not Gimp.RunMode: # Yes, I know this is wrong. What should it be?
        raise TypeError('procedure %s argument %d is not the correct type Gimp.RunMode, instead, it is type %s.'
                        % (proc_name, 0, arg_zero_type))
```

The `TypeError` is always raised, because "GType GimpRunMode" is not `Gimp.RunMode`, nor `Gimp.RunMode.__gtype__`, or anything I have guessed at. I don't know how to compare `arg_zero_type` to the type of classes like `Gimp.RunMode` in Python 3.0
What might work?